# Interface translation - Body, Title built-in interface

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I use i18n and I10n_client to translate English to Dutch in my web page, however some interface variables are not changing.

I searched 'Body' and try to replace it with its Dutch word, it doesnt take effect no matter what I do http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/831/searchbody1.png/

and http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/576/searchbody2.png

How can I change this type of built in interfaces. I cant change "Title" as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If having it only in Dutch is enough for you, you could change it to Dutch directly in the Edit content type form; go to Admin -> Content -> Content types, select edit for the one you want to change. You can set a title and body label in the "Submission form settings" fieldset.

There is a bug report open for this, see http://drupal.org/node/1016006.

I also found some reports that this *should* work now with multiple languages, with i18n: http://drupal.org/node/149349#comment-1135605.

Comment: Thx a lot Berdir, it worked just like I wanted.  I use only Dutch indeed